# Why should you recompose Unicode (NFC) on the way out?

Tags: perl, unicode

TomC recommends decomposing Unicode characters on the way in, and recomposing on the way out (http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perl-unicode-cookbook-always-decompose-and-recompose.html).

The former makes perfect sense to me, but I can't see why he recommends recomposing on the way out. Potentially you could save a small amount of space if your text is heavy with European accented characters, but you're just pushing that on to someone else's decomposition function.

Are there any other obvious reasons I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ven'Tatsu writes in a comment, there is software that can handle composed characters but not decomposed characters. Though the opposite is theoretically possible too, I have never seen it in practice and expect it to be rare.

To just display a decomposed character, the rendering software needs to deal with combining diacritic marks. It does not suffice to find them in the font. The renderer needs to position the diacritic properly, using information about the dimensions of the base character. There are often problems with this, resulting in poor rendering—especially if the rendering uses the diacritic from a different font! The result can hardly be better than what is achieved by simply displaying the glyph of a precomposed character like “é”, designed by a typographer.

(Rendering software can also analyze the situation and effectively map the decomposed character to a precomposed character. But that would require extra code.)

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense

Comment: This is not fully correct, however: "the rendering software needs to deal with combining diacritic marks" -- the decomposed characters are not necessarily are in the Composing Marks category, for example, the entire Hangul Syllables block, `U+AC00 - U+D7AF` decomposes into letters in the Hangul Jamo, `U+1100 - U+11FF` block. For example `U+AC00` decomposes into `U+1100` and `U+1161` which are, again, letters (`Lo`) and not marks. But yes, the renderer would need to render two characters instead of one, with all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple: Most tools have limited Unicode support; they assume characters are in the NFC form.

For example, this is commonly how people compare strings:

```
perl -CSDA -e"use utf8; if ($ARGV[0] eq "Éric") { ... }"
```

And of course, the "É" is in NFC form (since that's what almost everything produces), so this program only accepts arguments in NFC form.

Comment: Is this really true or a gut feeling? I'm curious if there's a survey somewhere.

Comment: @brian d foy, In the millions of snippets I've seen on PerlMonks, I've (almost?) never seen anyone use NFC or NFD, yet I've seen plenty of `eq` and `m//`. And I've absolutely never ever seen anything in NFD form.

Comment: @brian d foy, Why question me on this and go on to make the same explanation (just more obfuscated)? Standardisation is only needed if people don't use pass their input through NFC or NFD, so your own post is an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It would make things like text editors simpler since the end user would expect one visible character to be one character not several. It also prevents issues with systems that don't treat decomposed characters as 'single' characters.

Other than that, I don't see a particular advantage.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that. Even in NFC, there are many graphemes that are made up of more than one character. There are many "visible char + combining char" combinations that don't have a precomposed version.

Comment: Perhaps. I guess as well it means you're more likely to get your text understood if it's incorrectly read as Latin-1. This doesn't seem like a big win, though.

Comment: @petersergeant: No that won't work. Only characters 1-128 look the same in Latin-1 and UTF-8. Characters 129-256 have the same _value_ but different encodings. e.g. 'é' has the value 0xe9. In Latin-1, that's also its encoding. In UTF-8 it becomes 0xc3a9 (two bytes). That explains the common 'Ã©' encoding errors that you see. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8 has the details.

Comment: I have run across software that can't manage to deal with a decomposed 'é' but can display the composed version without issues. If the expectation is to mostly deal with data that can be represented by precomposed characters than emitting it that way could improve compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should one normalization form so all the data have the same normalization, so why not choose the potentially shorter one?

As for someone else's decomposition, remember that you want to be strict with what you output but liberal with what you accept. :)

Comment: Well he's explicitly suggesting making use of both forms, rather than sticking to one.

Answer (score -3):

Tom Christiansen is an active participant on StackOverflow and answers a lot of Perl questions. There's a good chance he'll answer this question.

Certain character sequences such as `ff` can be represented in UTF-8 as either two Unicode characters `f` and `f`, or as a single Unicode character (`ff`). When you *decompose* your characters, you're making things like `ff` become two separate characters which would be important for sorting. You want this to be two separate letter `f` when you sort.

When you recompose UTF-8 `f` and `f`, they go back to the single UTF-8 character which would be important for displaying (you want them to format nicely) and for editing (you want to edit it as a single character).

Unfortunately, my theory falls apart with things like the Spanish ñ. This is represented as U+00F1 as a single character, and decomposes into U+006E (n) and U+0303 (in-place ~). Maybe Perl has the logic built in to handle this type of two UTF-8 decompose character representation.

Comment: It's not that they go back to a single "UTF-8 character", but that they compose to a single code point which you then encode. The encoding doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, but that's wrong. `perl -MUnicode::Normalize -E"$_ = chr(0xFB00); say length $_; say length NFD $_;"` Output is one for both. "ﬀ" does not decompose to "f"+"f". (NKFD does, but that's something else.) Similarly, "f"+"f" will never compose to "ﬀ". They're simply not equivalent.